# Unable to get bearer token for Anypoint Platform with MFA enabled

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

I was using the https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login endpoint with my user credentials to get a bearer token earlier and it worked fine.

However I now have MFA enabled with Salesforce Authenticator on my Anypoint Platfrom and hence the above call returns

```
{
    "url": "https://verify.salesforce.com/verify/",
    "body": {
        "request": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6Imp3dCIsImtpZCI6ImFueXBvaW50X2lhbV9wcm9kLWMyYy04MC0xNjc0OTUwNDIzNTQ1IiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIn0.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.oadOPrB54dJp0xEHQwmy14vwGx3_vpCg75FHrvmpga-ioUD-M9f06yCWp3BXUmt6b9YoDVo4iZzidEZXOA5g9w"
    }
}
```

This is not the bearer token and I am at a loss to understand what needs to be done to generate the bearer token with MFA enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining an access token for a process will no longer work once [Multi Factor Authentication (MFA)](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/multi-factor-authentication) is enabled for an Anypoint Platform account. For security reasons user accounts should have MFA enabled, preventing them to use the same credentials to get a token. Usually a token is used in automated processes, scripts or applications. Though some exceptions are possible by the administrator of your org, MuleSoft will [increasingly restrict](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/MFA-requirement-for-all-MuleSoft-Anypoint-Platform-users) such exceptions over time because of security concerns.

For those situations the strongly recommended method is to create [Connected Application](https://docs.mulesoft.com/access-management/connected-apps-org-admin) credentials that can be used instead of user credentials.